# Prevent OS X from switching my keyboard layout when password fields are focused

Tags: keyboard

Some months ago, I switched to the [Colemak keyboard layout](http://colemak.com), which is mostly great. But, there is one annoyance that is imposed by OS X.

When the OS pops up a confirmation dialog to ask me to type my password in order to authorize an app for higher privileges, the OS switches my keyboard layout back to QWERTY whenever the password field of this dialog is focused. Not only that, but the OS prevents me from changing the layout back as long as that field has focus.

Now, I am perfectly able to type my password on the Colemak keyboard. In fact, I'm much better at it now than I am at typing it on QWERTY. I want this behavior to stop. Unfortunately, I can find no setting for this, neither in system preferences nor in a `defaults read` dump. But just because I can't find it doesn't mean it doesn't exist. Does anyone know how to fix this?

I'm running OS X 10.7.2 on a MacBookPro 3,1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put the `.keylayout` in `/Library/Keyboard Layouts/` instead of `~/Library/Keyboard Layouts/`.

Comment: Naturally, I never would have thought to try that. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like this information should be included on the [Colemak for Mac wiki page](http://colemak.com/wiki/index.php?title=Mac).