# Change American keyboard icon in menu bar to black and white

Tags: keyboard, finder, icon, menu-bar

How can I change the American keyboard icon my menu bar from a colored icon to black and white?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do that would be to create a duplicate layout with a custom .icns file using an app like Ukelele.

http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele

Comment: But remember to save it [as a bundle](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44906/how-to-define-lions-key-variations-in-a-keylayout-file) to [the root library](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34040). There's also a hacky way to [disable the default input methods](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44921/how-to-remove-or-disable-a-default-keyboard-layout).